# Unable to cross compile PostgreSQL with OpenSSL, fails on <openssl/opensslconf.h> not found - despite specifying include search path

Tags: linux, postgresql, openssl, autotools, autoconf

I am trying to cross compile PostgreSQL on an x86 host for an AArch64 target, and want to compile with OpenSSL support.

I already went ahead and successfully cross compiled OpenSSL for AArch64 using the following arguments:

```
../Configure linux-aarch64 --prefix=$(pwd)/packaged no-dso --cross-compile-prefix="/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-"
make -j$(nproc)
make -j$(nproc) install
```

Now on to cross compiling PostgreSQL, I am using the following build script:

```
test -e postgresql-12.2.tar.gz || wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v12.2/postgresql-12.2.tar.gz
test -e postgresql-12.2 || tar -xzvf postgresql-12.2.tar.gz
cd postgresql-12.2
test -e build_aarch64 && rm -rf build_aarch64
mkdir build_aarch64
cd build_aarch64
../configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --without-readline --without-zlib CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-fPIC" CPPFLAGS="-fPIC" --prefix=$PWD/packaged USE_DEV_URANDOM=1 --with-openssl --with-libraries=../../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1k/build_aarch64/packaged/lib/ --with-includes=../../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1k/build_aarch64/packaged/include/
make -j$(nproc)
```

The output of the configure commands shows that the include directory has been properly set:

```
configure: using CPPFLAGS=-fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE  -I../../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1k/build_aarch64/packaged/include/
configure: using LDFLAGS=  -L../../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1k/build_aarch64/packaged/lib/
```

Running the `make` command fails on:

```
/usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13:11: fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory
   13 | # include <openssl/opensslconf.h>
```

However if I run `find ../../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1k/build_aarch64/packaged/include/ | grep opensslconf.h` it outputs:

```
../../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1k/build_aarch64/packaged/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
```

so the file is definitely there in the include paths. Is this a bug? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: `/usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13:11: fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h:` that error message (namely the `PATH`) suggests that `make` is looking in your build-systems `/usr`, not in your cross-compile environment?

Comment: I didn't even catch that, thanks @tink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, looks like I had to use absolute paths instead of relative paths for the search directories:

```
../configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --without-readline --without-zlib CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-fPIC" CPPFLAGS="-fPIC" --prefix=$PWD/packaged USE_DEV_URANDOM=1 --with-openssl --with-libraries=$(pwd)/../../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1k/build_aarch64/packaged/lib/ --with-includes=$(pwd)/../../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1k/build_aarch64/packaged/include/
```

So basically just added `$(pwd)/` to the start of the search directory paths.